# How to change a JSON value from String to int?

Tags: javascript, json, api, casting, int

Trying to pull JSON values from here:
https://covid-19api.com/api/all-today

However, the first item is cast as a string as opposed to an int. This is my testing code so far, I'm not sure how to cast the item as an int rather than a string.

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://covid-19api.com/api/all-today", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    let nconf = result.confirmed;
    document.getElementById('nconf').innerHTML = nconf.toLocaleString('en');
    
    let ndeath = result.deaths;
    document.getElementById('ndeath').innerHTML = ndeath.toLocaleString('en');
    
    let nrecov = result.recovered;
    document.getElementById('nrecov').innerHTML = nrecov.toLocaleString('en');
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: `let nrecov = parseInt(result.recovered)` ?

Comment: +1 to @ABGR. I'd just add the radix (the mathematical base and second param of parseInt) `let nrecov = parseInt(result.recovered, 10)`

Comment: @ABGR don't forget the radix 

Comment: Damn I love this platform thank you guys. Can't believe it was that simple

Comment: @evolutionxbox that's optional I guess. However, it's good to add  I think

Comment: try `let nconf = +result.confirmed;`

Comment: @NathanBrown just on another note, why do you actually want to cast into `int`, String would do just as well.

Comment: @Mario woah cool - is there any downside of that versus parseInt?

Comment: @ABGR My guess is so he can leverage Number.prototype.toLocaleString()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: @coloradocolby yup that makes sence

Comment: Cause the rest of the data is in INT and it automatically adds commas for values in thousands, where as a string is just a bunch of numbers, so it wasn't aesthetically pleasing @ABGR

Comment: about Numeric conversion usnig unary +, perhaps what you should take into account is that parseInt will try to obtain an integer so that if you pass as argument `"1.5"` it will get `1` and its passing `"1aaa5"` will return `1`, while unary + when trying to convert `"1.5"` will return `1.5` and in the case of `"1aaa5"` `NaN` will return, in your case `result.confirmed` will be an integer, so it is indistinct which method to use, only it is much shorter to write. Finally using unary + is the same as using Number ("1.5")

Comment: I think the answer to your question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript,

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to cast the string into `int`

```
 let nrecov = parseInt(result.recovered, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete solution. Seems odd that the API returns `deaths` and `recovered` as integers but not `confirmed` lol  ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <p id="nconf"></p>
    <p id="ndeath"></p>
    <p id="nrecov"></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    fetch("https://covid-19api.com/api/all-today", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("result", result);
        let nconf = parseInt(result.confirmed, 10);
        document.getElementById("nconf").innerHTML = nconf.toLocaleString("en");

        let ndeath = result.deaths;
        document.getElementById("ndeath").innerHTML = ndeath.toLocaleString(
          "en"
        );

        let nrecov = result.recovered;
        document.getElementById("nrecov").innerHTML = nrecov.toLocaleString(
          "en"
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  </script>
</html>
```